# java swing thread callback

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to write some client/server application using swing.
I have a problem with threads communication. I can't understand how to send some data from EDT back to running thread.

```
class SwingUI extends JFrame implements IUpdater{

    @Override
    public void askPermission(String str) {
        int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, str);
        //  (?)Send i back
    }

}

class Connection implements Runnable{

    IUpdater updater;

    Connection(IUpdater u){updater = u;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String command = "download_file"; //=getCommand(); from a socket
        if(command.equals("download_file")){

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updater.askPermition(command);
                }
            });
            //  (?)wait until user answers
            //  int answ = getAnswer();
            //  if answ == OK
            System.out.println("Sending_File");
            //  if answ == DENY
            //System.out.println("Denied");
        }
    }

}



interface IUpdater{
    void askPermission(String str);
}
```

I need to get somehow response from userUI. Maybe not just int value but List object.

E.g after connection I need to prepare some data for certain client in userForm and then send it. What should I do?

Swingworker allows only to publish data to EDT or fire events which EDT's listening, not to receive messages.

Also I have to make running thread wait somehow. I'm not sure that sleep(n) until some variable changes is a good idea but I do not know how to use monitors in this case and should I. Maybe there are some design patterns solving it?

I'm sure that it is a common situation but I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: You should capture those parameters before the thread starts, not in the middle of its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads just execute Runnables, they cannot send/receive messages or values, the Runnables do that. But you cannot get a value from an interface method that only takes a String and does not return anything. So, first update the interface:

```
public interface IUpdater {
    int askPermission(String str);
}
```

Next, define a runnable that can call the interface method and store the result:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
public class AskUser implements Runnable {

    final CountDownLatch userInput = new CountDownLatch(1);
    IUpdater updater;
    String command;
    volatile int result;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            result = updater.askPermission(command);
        } finally {
            userInput.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

The `CountDownLatch` gives one thread the opportunity to wait for another thread (or more accurate: to let a runnable reach a certain state). The updated `Connection` implementation shows this little trick:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

    IUpdater updater;
    Connection(IUpdater u){updater = u;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String command = "download_file"; //=getCommand(); from a socket
        if(command.equals("download_file")) {

            AskUser ask = new AskUser();
            ask.command = command;
            ask.updater = updater;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ask);
            try {
                ask.userInput.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // waiting for user input was interrupted
            }
            System.out.println("Result: " + ask.result);
        }
    }
}
```

In general, if you have trouble getting values from a Runnable, make the Runnable a separate class and see if that can resolve the trouble. There are tricks you can use for shortcuts (so you do not have to create a separate class for the Runnable), but that requires specific knowledge and is harder to maintain. 

The `CountDownLatch` trick to get different Runnables to sync or know each other's state, I use often. Given proper variable names, it should be obvious what is happening.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for that! P.S.But shouldn't I synchronize variable result (adding getter and setter synchronized)?

Comment: @VaWizard No need to synchronize since no threads read/write the variable _at the same time_, but to ensure a new/updated value is seen by all threads, `volatile` is probably not a bad idea (I updated the answer).